# MTP: Unable to show folder

Tags: pantheon-files, mtp, odin

can't open my android via pantheon-files, have tried to install go-mtpfs or mtpfs-tools.

[image: MTP errors]

Comment: I have a similar problem, but in my case when connecting a cell phone. the file manager shows and immediately hides it over and over again.

Comment: same here, a workaround is to access it using a terminal... `cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/` (the number 1000 is the user id, if your is different get it with the command `id`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a regression due to a major re-write of the sidebar code. There is an issue report already here: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1781

There is a PR awaiting review and approval here: https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1752 which seems to fix this issue although that was its main aim.